# Script not running properly after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm building my own portfolio website on Wordpress and writing almost the whole code without plugins. The website features a home page with a dynamic 'custom post types' grid that I've implemented an Ajax filter according to the post taxonomy/category, reordering the posts according to the filter. This script runs on script.js:

```
(function ($) {

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.js-filter-item').removeClass('active');
      $('.js-filter').addClass('fade');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      setTimeout(function () {
        $('.js-filter').removeClass('fade');
      }, 500);
      var category = $(this).data('category');
      $.ajax({
        url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
        data: { action: 'filter', category: category },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (result) {
          // $('.js-filter').html(result);
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('.js-filter').html(result);
          }, 200);
        },
        error: function (result) {
          console.warn(result);
        }
      })
    });
  });
```

I've also implemented a custom tooltip that follows the cursor and shows the post title on hover, as follows. This is running on the home page php file between  tags:

```
var follower = $('.cursor-follower');
var posX = 0,
  posY = 0;
var mouseX = 0,
  mouseY = 0;
 
$('body').on('mousemove', function (e) {
  mouseX = e.clientX;
  mouseY = e.clientY;
  posX += (mouseX - posX) / 2;
            posY += (mouseY - posY) / 2;
  
  $('.cursor-follower').css(
    'top', (posY - 20) + 'px'
);
$('.cursor-follower').css(
    'left', (posX + 50) + 'px'
);
});

$('.animated-cursor').on('mouseenter', function () {
 console.log('olaaaaa');
  var dataTitle = $(this).attr('data-cursor-title');
  // var dataTags = $(this).attr('data-cursor-tags');
  follower.html(dataTitle + '<br>');
  follower.addClass('active');
});
$('.animated-cursor').on('mouseleave', function () {
  follower.removeClass('active');
});
```

And the query for the post grid ("animated-cursor" class and data-cursor-title are the relevant attributes):

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>
    <div class="reveal item animated-cursor" data-cursor-title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php $pagina = get_page_by_title('<?php the_title(); ?>') ?>
          <img src="<?php the_field('imagem_capa', $pagina); ?>" alt="">
          <div class="post-info">
          <div>
            <h3><?php echo wp_strip_all_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolio_cat', '', ', ', '' )) ?></h3>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <?php
        endwhile; 
      endif; 
      wp_reset_postdata(); 
       die();
```

Problem: the custom cursor tooltip doesn't work on element hover after using the Ajax filter. Everything runs fine as planned after page load, but it doesn't after anytime Ajax runs.

As far as I'm aware of (I'm a beginner on php, ajax, js), my script can only access the elements that are ready on page load. I've tried to make the script work after the Ajax call but I couldn't find a workaround. Would anyone have any suggestion? I suppose it mustn't be very complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which element is your custom tooltip?

Comment: `<div class="cursor-follower"></div>` this is the custom tooltip, its content between the tags changes depending on which of the .js-filter-item it's hovering

Comment: So what is the purpose of the .animated-cursor element? And I cannot see the .js-filter-item in your html elements.

Comment: my bad, ".js-filter-item" are the category filters attached to the ajax script. Each post is an ".item" element. The ".animated-cursor" class is given to which elements should the cursor display the tooltip while hovering. It works in a similar way as in here: https://cramdyn.com/work/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is: the javascript is binding on existed DOM, it's worked for the first rendering.
But after ajax call, The new DOM will be append to HTML. The new DOM will not binding function, so the hover is not work.

The solution is, Do not binding the event to DOM itself. you can binding the event listener on the parent note or page body
for example

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.animated-cursor', function () {
 console.log('olaaaaa');
  var dataTitle = $(this).attr('data-cursor-title');
  // var dataTags = $(this).attr('data-cursor-tags');
  follower.html(dataTitle + '<br>');
  follower.addClass('active');
});
$('body').on('mouseleave', '.animated-cursor', function () {
  follower.removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: thank you so much! that was exactly what I needed to make it work. Glad to know it's something so easy to make it work on any next similar situation

Comment: Your answer saved me today.  I was having a related issue with the .done code not working at all after an AJAX call and when I read your answer, I realized that I never removed the old form features I had setup in the HTML when I was trying to accomplish my task through traditional MVC procedures.  So when I was clicking "Create", the form was refreshing the screen after the AJAX call was made to my MVC controller.